# add condition for only upcoming Orders Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have to make some changes for order page, Actually i want that my changes is apply only for upcoming Orders not that Orders which are already have.

```
  So i thinks it should be like set Order id in **if** condition that if(Orderid > '5'){}.
  But How i dont know exactly what is condition for that.
```

Please reply thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the correct template for the changes under the `app/design/frontend` folder.  For example, the order info page is rendered by `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/info.phtml`.

Here you will find the line:

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
```

Here the `$_order` variable is defined, after this line anywhere in the template you can use:

```
<?php if ($_order->getEntityId() > 30):?>
<h1> HELLO WORLD </h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am wondering if you know the difference between `increment id` and `entity id`. `Increment id` is the one you see at the orders beginning with `#` and the `entity id` is the number you see in the url eg: `/sales/order/view/order_id/31/`

In the example above i used the `entity id`.